# Why won't my for loop be used in the output?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

These mailboxes were numbered 1 through 150, and beginning with mailbox 2, he opened the doors of all the even-numbered mailboxes, leaving the others closed. Next, beginning with mailbox 3, he went to every third mail box, opening its door if it were closed, and closing it if it were open. Then he repeated this procedure with every fourth mailbox, then every fifth mailbox, and so on.

I am trying to recreate this paragraph. I know my first and third function are find but for some reason my boolean is not using my loop in my second function in the output. Here is the code:

```
public class Lab {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Boolean[] mailboxarray = new Boolean[150];

        closeMailboxes(mailboxarray);
        doCrazyMailman(mailboxarray);
        showMailboxstate(mailboxarray);
    }

    /** 
     * purpose: 
     * pre-condition: 
     * post-condition:
     * @param mailboxarray
     */
    public static void closeMailboxes(Boolean[] mailboxarray) {
        for (int i = 0; i <150; i++) {
            mailboxarray[i] = Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }

    /** 
     * purpose: 
     * pre-condition: 
     * post-condition:
     * @param mailboxarray
     */
    public static void doCrazyMailman(Boolean[] mailboxarray) {
        // to help you with troubleshooting, I will add some outputs
        // it is always beneficial to be able to see what's your program
        // is actually doing right now
        for (int i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
           for (int j = i; j < 150;j=j+i+1) {











                        }
        }
    }

    /** 
     * purpose: 
     * pre-condition: 
     * post-condition:
     */
    public static void showMailboxstate(Boolean[] mailboxarray) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
           int number = i + 1;

           // this will output only closed doors 
           // as shown in assignment's screenshot
           // it reads next: 
           // if the current boolean is FALSE - display message
           if (!mailboxarray[i])


              System.out.println("Door " + number +  " is closed");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Is it possible you forgot to add some of your code? Your doCrazyMailman method is empty apart from the two loops, and if you want us to help we need to see the array indexes/assignments

Answer (score 0):

Adapted your code to do the homework.
The catch is to look carefully at array indexes and know the use of negate boolean values.

```
class Lab {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Boolean[] mailboxarray = new Boolean[150];

    closeMailboxes(mailboxarray);
    doCrazyMailman(mailboxarray);
    showMailboxstate(mailboxarray);
}

/**
 * purpose: pre-condition: post-condition:
 * 
 * @param mailboxarray
 */
public static void closeMailboxes(Boolean[] mailboxarray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        mailboxarray[i] = Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}

/**
 * purpose: pre-condition: post-condition:
 * 
 * @param mailboxarray
 */
public static void doCrazyMailman(Boolean[] mailboxarray) {
// to help you with troubleshooting, I will add some outputs
// it is always beneficial to be able to see what's your program
// is actually doing right now
    for (int i = 2; i <= 150; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= 150; j = i + j) {
            // switch open-close by negate
            // work with real case counter and take care to modify at proper place in arr
            mailboxarray[j - 1] = !mailboxarray[j - 1];
            // System.out.println(i + ":" + j + ":" + !mailboxarray[j - 1] + ":" + 
            // mailboxarray[j - 1]);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * purpose: pre-condition: post-condition:
 */
public static void showMailboxstate(Boolean[] mailboxarray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        int number = i + 1;

// this will output only closed doors
// as shown in assignment's screenshot
// it reads next:
// if the current boolean is FALSE - display message
        if (!mailboxarray[i])

            System.out.println("Door " + number + " is closed");
    }
}
}
```

output

```
Door 1 is closed
Door 4 is closed
Door 9 is closed
Door 16 is closed
Door 25 is closed
Door 36 is closed
Door 49 is closed
Door 64 is closed
Door 81 is closed
Door 100 is closed
Door 121 is closed
Door 144 is closed
```